# Plugin for aroundSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder Throwing Error

Tags: magento2, module, plugin, di

I have a plugin that i want to intercept aroundSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder, but it is giving me an error. Here is how it is set up:

Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
          <arguments>
              <argument name="columns">
                  <item name="veratad_action" xsi:type="string">sales_order.veratad_action</item>
              </argument>
          </arguments>
      </virtualType>
      <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement">
              <plugin name="veratad_ageverification_before_order" type="Veratad\AgeVerification\Plugin\Ageverification" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
        </type>
    </config>
```

Vendor/Module/Plugin/Ageverification.php

```
    namespace Veratad\AgeVerification\Plugin;

    use Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement as CheckoutPaymentInformationManagement;

    class Ageverification
    {

      public function aroundSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(CheckoutGuestPaymentInformationManagement $subject){

        return ($subject);

   }

}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Veratad\AgeVerification\Plugin\Ageverification::aroundSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder() must be an instance of Veratad\AgeVerification\Plugin\CheckoutGuestPaymentInformationManagement, instance of Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor given, called in /home/z3hjb5ti7gx1/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 135 and defined in /home/z3hjb5ti7gx1/public_html/magento/app/code/Veratad/AgeVerification/Plugin/Ageverification.php:10
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/z3hjb5ti7gx1/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Veratad\AgeVerification\Plugin\Ageverification->aroundSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(Object(Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'f2c487019bcfd1b...', 'tcanfarotta2@v....', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))
    #1 /home/z3hjb5ti7gx1/public_html/magento/ve in /home/z3hjb5ti7gx1/public_html/magento/app/code/Veratad/AgeVerification/Plugin/Ageverification.php on line 10
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

New Plugin Code:

```
      namespace Veratad\AgeVerification\Plugin;

      use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;

      class Ageverification {

          public function aroundSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
          \Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement $subject,
          callable $proceed,
          \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
          \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null) {
              $action = "FAIL";
              if($action == "FAIL"){
                      throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('You have not been age verified.'));
                      return false;
              }else{
                  $proceed($paymentMethod,$billingAddress);
          }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You plugin  class  is wrong, The **aroundSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder()** should have **4 parameters**.

1. $subject which object of `Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement`.
2. second callback $proceed.
3. 3rd parameter is   $paymentMethod which instance of `\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface`.

   4 .4th parameter is    $billingAddress which instance of `Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface` .

Please check how to use around plugin https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

```
<?php
namespace Veratad\AgeVerification\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement as CheckoutPaymentInformationManagement;

class Ageverification {

    public function aroundSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    CheckoutGuestPaymentInformationManagement $subject, callable $proceed,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
    ) {

        $proceed($paymentMethod,$billingAddress);
    }

}
```

Comment: How can i stop this method from proceeding?

Comment: Sorry donot  understand . you want to stop the execution of rest of codes of this method?

Comment: Yes, conditionally. I have to check a third party API and depending on response I want the payment and place order to save or i want to stop it from saving.

Comment: then remove `$proceed($paymentMethod,$billingAddress);` from around method and return  what you want to return  and also throw an excpetion from this around that will show  at  checkout page

Comment: I am getting a new error:

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Veratad\AgeVerification\Plugin\Ageverification::aroundSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder() must implement interface Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface, integer given, called in /home/z3hjb5ti7gx1/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 135 and defined in /home/z3hjb5ti7gx1/public_html/magento/app/code/Veratad/AgeVerification/Plugin/Ageverification.php:9

Comment: I have added the new plugin code above